# Unit tests work in Resharper but not MSTests

Tags: .net-core, sdk, mstest

We recently moved to .NET Core 3.1, and then back to 2.2 until we could update some dependencies that did not work under 3.1. After this, tests in MS Test would not run due to the reason below.

> [1/2/2020 1:32:44.790 PM] ---------- Discovery started ----------
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Testhost process exited with error: It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
>
> The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '2.2.0' was not found.
>     - The following frameworks were found:
>         3.0.1 at [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>         3.1.0 at [C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App]
>   You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.
>
> The specified framework can be found at:
>     - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=2.2.0&arch=x86&rid=win10-x86
>   . Please check the diagnostic logs for more information.

The tests run in Resharper.

I reinstalled .NET Core 2.2.8 SDK from [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.2) but that did not help. After installation I noticed that `C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App` did not have a folder for 2.2.8.

How do I get the tests to run in MS Test and/or get that folder populated (and why wasn't it populated after installing that version for that matter)?

Comment: I've had the same problem. No solution yet, but it seems like it's starting to look at the x86 dotnet directory when it previously looked for it in the x64 program files/dotnet directory.